# How can I get Youtube video length?

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I'm trying to automate youtube via selenium
but I'm stuck in between
I want to create a program that will take list of song which user have to listen and then it will play the song on youtube one after the other automatically. So I'm able to play one song but after that i dont know how to get length of the video automatically and then wait until the video ends and then search the next song and play it.(like a loop until the list ends)
plz help me
My code

```
''''
import os
from selenium import webdriver
from getpass import getpass
from time import sleep
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

# Adblocker Extension 
executable_path = "/webdrivers"
os.environ["webdriver.chrome.driver"] = executable_path
chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_extension('E:\\ad\\ads4.crx')

# Chrome Driver
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chrome_options)
driver.get("https://youtube.com.")
sleep(2)

# Song name to search :
searchbox = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/ytd-app/div/div/ytd-masthead/div[3]/div[2]/ytd-searchbox/form/div/div[1]/input')
searchbox.send_keys('Can e Sanem - Mean It')

searchbutton = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="search-icon-legacy"]')
searchbutton.click()

# Play the first song on the list
playbutton = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/ytd-app/div/ytd-page-manager/ytd-search/div[1]/ytd-two-column-search-results-renderer/div/ytd-section-list-renderer/div[2]/ytd-item-section-renderer/div[3]/ytd-video-renderer[1]/div[1]/div/div[1]/div/h3/a/yt-formatted-string')
playbutton.click()

# Play the nect song after the first ends
# playnext = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/ytd-app/div/ytd-page-manager/ytd-watch-flexy/div[4]/div[1]/div/div[11]/ytd-watch-next-secondary-results-renderer/div[2]/ytd-compact-autoplay-renderer/div[2]/ytd-compact-video-renderer/div[1]/div')
# playnext.click()

''''
```

Comment: Is there a specific issue? Have you tried anything, done any research? Please see [ask], [help/on-topic].

Answer (score 2):

To do that its needed to execute some JS code to get the duration, and the youtube player api has a function for that.

```py
video_len = self.driver.execute_script("return document.getElementById('movie_player').getDuration()")

video_len = int(video_len) / 60

print(f"{video_dur}/{video_len})
```

Comment: @diven I will omit the explanation of ```self```  ```driver``` and ```execute_script``` because you have the official documentation for this. If there is something that you don't understand about any selenium method just ask. 

Basically ```video_len``` has inside a return in Javascript with the Id of your player and it calls the Js Methof that i told you need.

Then to get the minutes just divide the result by 60 (seconds),

Finally with ```print``` show an output with the format bellow - eg: "1:20 / 5:00". (current / lenght)

Answer (score -1):

Try this line to get video duration time:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//span[@class="ytp-time-duration"]').text
```

If you want to get time as seconds:

```
import time
import datetime

duration = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//span[@class="ytp-time-duration"]').text
_time = time.strptime(duration, '%M:%S')
seconds = datetime.timedelta(minutes=_time.tm_min,seconds=_time.tm_sec).total_seconds()
```